# What does Observable<MyResponse> denote

Tags: typescript, observable

I am new to typescript and observables. I saw a piece of code like below

```
 getCalulatedValues = (postValue: MyRequest): Observable<MyResponse> => {

        return this._http.post(this.actionUrl, JSON.stringify(postValue), { headers: this.headers })
            .map((response: Response) => <MyResponse>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

In this what does (postValue: MyRequest): Observable denote? i understand that postValue is of type MyRequest, but did not understand second part of `:` i.e `Observable<MyResponse>`. What does the whole statement `(postValue: MyRequest): Observable<MyResponse>` 
mean?

Comment: Observable is a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), you need to include what it's an observable *of*.

Answer (score -1):

It defines a function, named `getCalulatedValues`, taking an argument of type `MyRequest` named `postValue`, and returning a value of type `Observable<MyResponse>`.